# How to skip line in MVC Controller if enclosure not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

I have aggregated many rss feeds, and some of source feeds have  tag for media, but many sources don`t have it. 
How to skip the line Image

**Image = ((string)x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url")),**

in controller if  tag not exist for record, because if not it tag my site downing?

**Contoller code:**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        WebClient wclient = new WebClient(/*string RSSURL*/);
        wclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var RSSURL = "http://localhost:60348/Rss";
        string RSSData = wclient.DownloadString(RSSURL);
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(RSSData);

        var RSSFeedData = (from x in xml.Descendants("item")

                               select new RSSFeed
                               {

                                  Title = ((string)x.Element("title")),
                                   Link = ((string)x.Element("link")),
                                   Description = ((string)x.Element("description")),
                                   PubDate = ((string)x.Element("pubDate")),
                 Image = ((string)x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url")),
                                   Kategorija = ((string)x.Element("category"))
    }
  );
            ViewBag.RssFeed = RSSFeedData;
            ViewBag.URL = RSSURL;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (?.) in VS 2015 and VS 2017
`Image = ((string)x.Element("enclosure")?.Attribute("url"))`
or [conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) in older version VS 
`Image = x.Element("enclosure") != null ? ((string)x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url")) : null`